# Bootstrap Toast not showing when Bootstrap Modal is closed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, toast

I'm developing a company directory app for a company to keep track of its employees, its departments and locations and which employees are in which department and which is in which location and so on etc. My app needs to ask the user to confirm before they make changes to the data in the database which it does and the change is successfully made in the DB and the code 200 is returned but it also needs to confirm to the user that the changes have been successfully made. I'm trying to use Bootstrap Toast to display a message to the user but I cannot seem to get the toast to appear. As you'll see I've placed the HTML for the toast within my code and I'm calling the toast within the callback for the post request using:-

```
$('#successToast').toast('show');
```

however I cannot seem to get the toast to appear.

There are no errors showing in my console etc and I have checked the entire page to ensure it's not appearing below the rest of the content at the bottom but it's not. I'm very much stumped and unsure where to look now to resolve the issue.

My code: (I've only posted the relevant sections of code but I can post all my code if needed)

index.html

```
<!--Form to add location-->
          <div class="modal fade" id="addLocationModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Location</h5>
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                
                <form id="addLocationForm" onsubmit="addLocation()">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="locationName" id="newLocationName" placeholder="Location Name..." >
                </div>
                <div id="add-location-modal-footer" class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                  <button id="add-location-step-one-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </div>
                <div id="add-location-confirmation-modal-footer" class="modal-footer">
                  <p>Are you sure you wish to add <span id="locationToAdd"></span> ?</p>
                  <button id="add-location-go-back-button" type="button" class="btn btn-danger" >Go Back</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
              </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--End of add location-->
    <!--Success Toast-->
              <div id="successToast" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" style="position: relative; min-height: 200px;" data-delay="10000">
                <div class="toast" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0;">
                  <div class="toast-header">
                    <img src="" class="rounded mr-2" alt="">
                    <strong class="mr-auto">Success</strong>
                    <button type="button" class="ml-2 mb-1 close" data-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="toast-body">
                    <span id="changedVariable"></span> <span id="changeAdjective"></span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            
        </body>
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            
            <script src="js/script.js"></script>
            
            <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5dd4ce85ea.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

script.js:

```
$('#add-location-step-one-button').on('click', function(){
  
  $('#newLocationName').attr("disabled", true);
  $('#add-location-modal-footer').hide();
  $('#add-location-confirmation-modal-footer').show();
  let newLocation = $('#newLocationName').val();
  $('#locationToAdd').html(newLocation);
  
});

$('#add-location-go-back-button').on('click', function(){
  $('#add-location-confirmation-modal-footer').hide();
  $('#newLocationName').attr("disabled", false);
  $('#add-location-modal-footer').show();
});

function addLocation() {
  let newLocation = $('#newLocationName').val();


  $.post(
    'php/insertLocation.php'
  ,
  {
    newLocation: newLocation
  },
  function(data){
    if(data.status.code == 200){
      $('#changedVariable').html(newLocation);
      $('#changeAdjective').html('added');
      $('#successToast').toast('show');
    }
  }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From bootstrap docs. "Toasts are opt-in for performance reasons, so you must initialize them yourself."

Checkout their docs

```
var toastElList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.toast'))
var toastList = toastElList.map(function (toastEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Toast(toastEl, option)
})
```